# select menu with checkmark next to selected item

Tags: html, css, select

[image]

how does one get the checkmark next to the selected item in a very simple HTML select menu?
I tried having the following in a external CSS file that is linked.

```
select option:selected::after {
    content: '/f00c';
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You would need a widget like "select2" or something. But please post your HTML

Comment: You can't do this with a traditional `<select>` element, you have to rebuild the element with HTML/JS to get the desired effect. Best suggestion is to use a library like select2 (if you use jquery) or any other library for this job.